# PHP & MYSQL: Why mysql cannot read !empty?

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to search multiple fields in database where the user also can search just for one input. But now, the problem is sql don't want to read the (!empty) in if else condition (if i just want to search 1 input). BUt then if i fill all the searching field, it displays well.
Please correct if i do wrong. TQSM!

so, here is my code:

```
 if(!empty($_POST['search4']))
{
    $tarikh = $_POST['tahun'];
$tempat= $_POST['tempat'];
$sesi = $_POST['sesi'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
echo $tarikh;
echo $tempat;

    $field = array($tarikh,$tempat,$sesi,$status);
    $conditions = array();

foreach($field as $fields)
{
    if(isset($_POST[$fields]))
    {

        $conditions[] = "'$fields' LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$fields])."%'";

    }
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM tempahanbilik WHERE status!='BELUM DIPROSES' AND kosong = 'tidak' AND MONTH(tarikh) = 5 AND YEAR(tarikh) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(tarikh2) = YEAR(CURDATE()) ";
            if(count($conditions>0))
            {
                $query .="WHERE" .implode('OR',$conditions);
            }


$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error._LINE_);

        $total = $result->num_rows;

        if($total>0)
        {
            $total =1;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {       
                $kp = $row['PenggunanoKP'];
                        $a = "SELECT * FROM pengguna WHERE PenggunanoKP = '$kp'";
                        $results = $mysqli->query($a) or die($mysqli->error._LINE_);
                     $rows = $results->fetch_assoc();

                //display the informations
        }               
    } 
    else
    {   
        echo"  
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td> 
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td> 
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>\n";        
    }
```

the error displays:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant _LINE_ - assumed '_LINE_' in C:\xampp\htdocs\booking\search.php on line 106
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE' at line 1_LINE_
```

Comment: SQL has nothing to do with that. We can't also tell since you didn't add how you populate those variables inside your `!empty`

Comment: What is the exact error ?

Comment: @yunandtidus it displays the else condition ( if the query is empty )

Comment: @hungrykoala ok, i already editted my question.

Comment: You can just omit this part `$tarikh && ` since you're already using `!empty`

Comment: It is unclear what you are posting in previous form (`search4`, `tarikh`, `status`...), of course `$_POST['search4']` needs to be set, to enter the `if` statement

Comment: @hungrykoala  now, it has error of the query :(

Comment: Now it works, show the errors to the query.

Comment: read what [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) does.

Comment: sorry.. im still unclear. so do i have to use  $x !=null instead of !empty? @hungrykoala

Comment: `!empty` is your best bet to check for not null and not empty variables. now tell us what are the errors of your query. So stick with `!empty`

Comment: basically,  for the previous form it is just drop down list input field. so, what can i do for $_POST['search4']? Sorry for asking you a quite dumb question because i'm a newbie on php @yunandtidus

Comment: the errors already solved, the tarikh && also already omitted. but now, it still not displaying the informations... :(

Comment: so you're able to execute this query `$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error._LINE_);`?

Comment: yes... is it ok if i'm using if(isset($_POST['search4'])) to retrieve values from previous form? @hungrykoala

Comment: you can just use `!empty($_POST)` to check if the post variable has values in it.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Instead of concatenating (badly) a bunch of conditions, consider making an `array` and then combining that with `implode` to join them with `" AND "` into a single clause. Pay *very* close attention to how your final statement comes out.

Comment: i've editted my code, @tadman as u said by applying array in it. but now it displays  an error. and i have no idea where is the mistake :(

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` is a deprecated function that was deleted in PHP 7 and has no business being here. You should push in placeholder values instead. Note that PDO makes this a *lot* easier than `mysqli` since it supports named placeholders and you can send a simple array to `execute()` instead. `mysqli` can do it but you have to hack around with [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) which is way more messy, but *necessary* to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to omit the other part of your if condition as you're already using `!empty`

From this:

```
if($tarikh && !empty($tarikh))
{
    $query .="AND YEAR(tarikh) = $tarikh AND YEAR(tarikh2) = $tarikh";
}
if($tempat && !empty($tempat))
{
    $query .="AND  tempat = '$tempat'";
}
if($sesi && !empty($sesi))
{
    $query .="AND masa = '$sesi'";
}
if($status && !empty($status))
{
    $query .="AND status = '$status'";
}
```

To this:

```
if(!empty($tarikh))
{
    $query .=" AND YEAR(tarikh) = $tarikh AND YEAR(tarikh2) = $tarikh ";
}
if(!empty($tempat))
{
    $query .=" AND  tempat = '$tempat' ";
}
if(!empty($sesi))
{
    $query .=" AND masa = '$sesi' ";
}
if(!empty($status))
{
    $query .=" AND status = '$status' ";
}
```

Also add some space before `AND` as your query will look like this otherwise:

```
AND YEAR(tarikh) = $tarikh AND YEAR(tarikh2) = $tarikhAND  tempat = '$tempat'AND masa = '$sesi'
```

which will return an error when those variables are changed with their current values.

Comment: Please explain why you would put so many spaces.. php is cutting away empty space, unless they are quoted